# Почему не запускается скрипт погоды?

Tags: javascript, django

Пытаюсь подключить на странице скрипт погоды. Но он почему то не работает. Вот код:

```
<div class="pogoda-script">
   <div class="widget-content"><!-- Gismeteo informer START -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://www.gismeteo.ru/assets/flat-ui/legacy/css/informer.min.css">
            <div class="gsInformer" style="width:209px;height:252px">
              <div class="gsIContent">
                <div id="cityLink">
                  <a href="https://www.gismeteo.ru/city/daily/4368/" target="_blank">Погода Москва</a>    </div>
                <div class="gsLinks">
                  <table>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                        <div class="leftCol">
                          <a href="https://www.gismeteo.ru" target="_blank">
                            <img alt="Gismeteo" title="Gismeteo" src="https://www.gismeteo.ru/assets/flat-ui/img/logo-mini2.png" align="middle" border="0" />
                            <span>Gismeteo</span>
                          </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="rightCol">
                          <a href="https://www.gismeteo.ru/city/weekly/4368/" target="_blank">Прогноз неделю</a>
                        </div>
                      </td>
                    </tr>
                  </table>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <script async src="https://www.gismeteo.ru/api/informer/getinformer/?hash=vHn537AuwOMnNo" type="text/javascript"></script>
   <!-- Gismeteo informer END --></div>
</div>
```

Почему скрипт не запускается?

Comment: А в консоли браузера (`CTRL + SHIFT + I`) нет ошибок?

Comment: на оф сайте написано что надо указать реальный домен  на котором будет находится информер и то что на других доменах он не будет работать

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Предполагаю, вы пытаетесь запустить на тестовом/локальном сервере.

Однако по ссылке https://www.gismeteo.ru/api/informer/getinformer/?hash=vHn537AuwOMnNo отдается пустой ответ. Что с очень большой долей вероятности означает, что запрос должен приходить с определенного домена — т.е. с указанием `Referer` в заголовке запроса. И если мое предположение верно — тестовый/локальный сервер указывает не оригинальный домен (который вы указывали при регистрации Информера) в заголовке запроса к API GisMeteo...

```
Referer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Referer

Comment: @Maxim Savin, Спасибо, уже разобрался.